# Does one absorb more nutrients from juices than the whole fruit?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients

I read on this [Doctoroz article](http://www.doctoroz.com/article/healing-properties-juicing):

> Some advocates for juicing may claim that your body absorbs more nutrients from juices than the whole fruit because the fruit’s fiber gets in the way.

Is there any scientific evidence supporting or infirming this claim?

Comment: Not sure about absorption but certainly can consume more in juice.  A glass of carrot juice is a lot of chewing.

Answer (score 4):

This might be true for some substances and false for others. For example, might be true for beta-carotene:

> Soluble fiber may inhibit ß-carotene absorption; therefore, consumption of juice may increase plasma ß-carotene concentrations more than whole fruits/vegetables in free-living populations.

Although,

> (...) most of this research was conducted in laboratory-based settings.

Source: "[Associations of soluble fiber, whole fruits/vegetables, and juice with plasma Beta-carotene concentrations in a free-living population of breast cancer survivors.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23127215)" (2012)

But lack of fiber may not be good for pectin:

> Apples are rich in polyphenols and pectin, two potentially bioactive constituents; however, these constituents segregate differently during processing into juice products and clear juice is free of pectin and other cell wall components. We conclude that **the fibre component is necessary** for the cholesterol-lowering effect of apples in healthy humans and that **clear apple juice may not be a suitable surrogate for the whole fruit** in nutritional recommendations.

Source: "[Intake of whole apples or clear apple juice has contrasting effects on plasma lipids in healthy volunteers.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23271615)"

Comment: Fibers definitely aid in the absorption of certain nutrients. One mechanism may be by delayed gastric emptying time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_fiber#cite_note-Eastwood-2